# Variance of the beta coefficient in linear regression

Tags: regression, variance, standard-error

I have a linear regression equation: $y=bx + a$.
Also standard error of the slope $b$ estimate is given and the sample size. Is it possible with this information to infer the variance of $b$?

Answer (score 1):

The standard error of an estimator can be seen as the standard deviation of this estimator. So, standard error is the same for an estimator as standard deviation for a sample. Hence, you only need to square your standard error in your regression output in order to get the variance of the coefficients.

Go to the Wikipedia article for standard error by clicking [here](http://The%20standard%20error%20(SE)%20is%20the%20standard%20deviation%20of%20the%20sampling%20distribution%20of%20a%20statistic.[1]). The first sentence is: *The standard error (SE) is the standard deviation of the sampling distribution of a statistic.*

Comment: In Bayesian approach yes, but in frequentionist you $b$ is *not* a random variable but a point estimate, so it has no variance. The same as confidence intervals does not tell you about 95% of possible values (they are SE-based).